# Extracting JSON data from public API, returning a promise

Tags: javascript, json

I want to extract an array from the public API, and all I'm receiving is a `promise`. How can I return the array from the API, outside my function?

Please have a look at the code I'm trying to implement:

```
var getMov = function() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/projects')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            JSON.parse(responseJson.movies);
            return responseJson.movies;
        })
};
console.log(getMov());
```

Let me know if you have any ideas, how to solve this promise issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the `then` method again.

```
getMov().then(function(movies) {
    // do smth with movies
});
```

According to the [promises specs](https://promisesaplus.com/) the argument of the `onFulfilled` function will be the returned value from the last exectuted `onFulfilled` method, which is your case return the `movies`.